# Unable to create multiple tables in PostgreSQL using Flask

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create multiple tables in one PostgreSQL database. The codes work fine for only one table 'data', when I tried to add another table 'user' and query the table, I got this error "AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'username'". Here are the codes, thank you for your help!

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app=Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]=....
db=SQLAlchemy(app)
class Data(db.Model):
    __tablename__='data'

    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    author_=db.Column(db.String(120))
    year_=db.Column(db.Integer)
    title_=db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, author_, year_,title_):
        self.author_=author_
        self.year_=year_
        self.title_=title_

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__='user'

    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    user_=db.Column(db.String(120))
    email_=db.Column(db.String(120))
    password_=db.Column(db.String(120))

    def __init__(self, user_,email_,password_):
        self.username=user_
        self.email=email_
        self.password=password_

db.create_all()
db.session.query(User).filter(User.username==username).scalar()
```

Comment: Error clearly says that you don't have an attribute `username` which is what you need to include in your model (not just `__init__` ).

Comment: `db.session.query(User).filter(User.user_==username).scalar()`. The table does not have a username column. It shouldn't be able to create a column if you set an attribute to `self`.

Comment: @ Underoos, how should I include the attribute in the model for this case?Thanks

Comment: @ Diptangsu Goswami, I don't understand. How should I change the codes? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your arguments are not same as in your declaration

```
def __init__(self, user_,email_,password_):
    self.user_=user_
    self.email_=email_
    self.password_=password_
```